# Dynamic scheduling in uipath orchestrator

Tags: uipath

I'm trying to schedule a bot which is being triggered from orchestrator every 3 hours. The process is basically an email automation. If the no of emails that is being processed is less than average, i want to trigger the bot.

Is there a cron expression that can help me with this type of scheduling?

Do let me know if there any other way to achieve this (like making a change in code or some other method).

Comment: You should always post some code showing what you've tried and others will gladly help

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something to determine when the criteria are met to trigger a job to run. This could be done from another automated process; a monitor, which in turn would invoke your email process, or from an outside source if you have a monitoring platform or another external source.

When triggered, you'll want to make a few calls to the Orchestrator API to start an adhoc/manual job.

1. Authenticate `/api/Account/Authenticate` (Assuming you are using local credentials and not Domain)
2. Get Job Key `/odata/Releases` (If you already know the key for the given process, you could hardcode it in the next step instead of calling this one each time)
3. Start Job `/odata/Jobs/UiPath.Server.Configuration.OData.StartJobs`

   Example request body:

   ```
   {
     "startInfo": {
       "ReleaseKey": "string",
       "Strategy": "All",
       "RobotIds": [
         0
       ],
       "NoOfRobots": 0,
       "JobsCount": 0,
       "Source": "Manual",
       "InputArguments": "string"
     }
   }
   ```
4. Check Status of Job `/odata/Jobs(jobid)`.

More information on the Orchestrator API can be found in [The UiPath ORchestrator Guide](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/). I'd also recommend checking out your swagger UI in Orchestrator, by adding `/swagger` onto the end of your Orchestrator URL. e.g. https://platform.uipath.com/swagger/

Answer (score 0):

To trigger your robot from studio you can use invoke power shell activity (https://activities.uipath.com/docs/invoke-power-shell) with -file / -f command to execute a workflow.

```
UiRobot -file "C:\UiPath\Project\Main.xaml"
```

For this you will have to navigate to the directory in which the Robot is installed.

You can find more information here: https://robot.uipath.com/docs/arguments-description.

**OR**

You can also make a HTTP request to the orchestrator API. You can find more information here: https://orchestrator.uipath.com/v2018.4/reference#jobs-requests

Comment: but i want to trigger the bot from orchestrator. i dont want to disturb the PC where studio is installed.

Comment: @Govind In that case you can use the orchestrator API, check the following page for more information https://orchestrator.uipath.com/v2018.4/reference#section-starting-a-job